# hook_form_alter isn't being called when node fails validation

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

I'm noticing that hook_form_alter isn't being called when a page has errors that display a message from form_set_error.  Changes to my form aren't taking effect, and the error page is effectively broken.

I've tried to output a dpm statement in hook_form_alter, but it isn't appearing on the error page.

Is there a way to get drupal to call the hook and alter the form?

Comment: I've found http://drupal.org/node/671574 which claims this is fixed in drupal 7, but it does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms are cached in Drupal so the form is loaded once (where your form_alter runs) and then it's loaded from cache to be reloaded when there are validation errors.

You should use an [#after_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#after_build) callback, which always gets run.

Just remember to return $element in your #after_build callback or you'll be getting WSODs.

Comment: is it possible to add elements to the form?  I'm adding a textarea when a value is set in a particular field.

Comment: Technically yes you can do anything with the form. That said, you might be better off adding the field in your form alter with #access FALSE and then setting it to TRUE in your after build if necessary.

Comment: If I add the field in the form_alter, it doesn't appear on the validation error page.  I decided to create the field in my after_build callback, but the #ajax callback is not being fired.  Autocomplete works fine.  When dealing with form_alter I found that I had to add the wrapper with `#printed => TRUE` to the root of the array, and then copy the field to the element I wanted it to display under.  I think the callback worked then because the field had already been recognized during rendering.  Do I need to call `field_default_form` or some other function to get ajax callbacks to work?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do with adding the extra field?  It doesn't appear in your validation error because #access was set to false, you could try checking for form_get_errors() in your after build and setting #access to true if there are any

Comment: I'm writing a module called text_field_reference that autocompletes to the value of a field in the recommendation content type I've created.  The recommendations match up to a finding select field that has integer point values (0, 1, 2, etc).  If the user changes the select field, I use an ajax call to display a textarea that autocompletes to a recommendation.  Its blur event replaces the field_text_reference field with a key representing the node that was referenced.  I'll be the first to admit it's kind of hackish.  The ajax callback to replace the reference field is intermittently working.

Comment: After adding an empty wrapper to the finding field for the textarea (it was in the alter hook before), the ajax callback started working.  At least I think this change was what fixed it.  Thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer.